Cross Referencing Equations with Hyperref: No Capital Letter
I'm using the packages amsmath, hyperref and cleveref to cross reference equations.
Is there any way to suppress the capital letter?
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[pdfa,hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    \label{eq1}
    x+y=z 
\end{align}
\autoref{eq1}
\end{document}

The output should be equation 1 instead of Equation 1.

As you already load the cleveref package, you could actually use it:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[pdfa,hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    \label{eq1}
    x+y=z 
\end{align}
test \cref{eq1}
\end{document}


